# Dynamic attributes in a jsp tag

Tags: java, jsp

I want to have a tag with dynamic attributes, like simple html tags, **e.g.** something like this:

```
<tags:superTag dynamicAttribute1="value" someOtherAttribute="valueOfSomeOther"/>
```

And in my implementation of tag I want to have something like this:

```
public class DynamicAttributesTag {

    private Map<String,String> dynamicAttributes;

    public Map<String, String> getDynamicAttributes() {
        return dynamicAttributes;
    }

    public void setDynamicAttributes(Map<String, String> dynamicAttributes) {
        this.dynamicAttributes = dynamicAttributes;
    }

    @Override
    protected int doTag() throws Exception {
        for (Map.Entry<String, String> dynamicAttribute : dynamicAttributes.entrySet()) {
            // do something
        }
        return 0;
    }
}
```

I want to point out that these dynamic attributes are going to be written by hands in a jsp, not just passed as Map like `${someMap}`. So is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: If I understand you correctly, this could be done with a `<dynamic-attributes>` tag in the TLD. For "jsp dynamic attributes example" Google gives you several promising results.

Comment: @icke Yes, it's exactly what I need. Thank you very much. You can add it as an answer and I'll accept it, but could you please also provide some example for future readers? Basically it's just implementing interface DynamicAttributes and tag <dynamic-attributes> in TLD.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You will have to enable dynamic attributes in your TLD, like so:

```
<tag>
    ...
    <dynamic-attributes>true</dynamic-attributes>
</tag>
```

And then have your tag handler class implement the `DynamicAttributes` interface:

```
public class DynamicAttributesTag extends SimpleTagSupport implements DynamicAttributes {
    ...
    public void setDynamicAttribute(String uri, String localName, Object value) throws JspException {
        // This gets called every time a dynamic attribute is set
        // You could add the (localName,value) pair to your dynamicAttributes map here
    }
    ...
}
```